# Renaming ASP MVC Project Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I recently needed to change the name of an intranet website FROM Spain, TO Monet. The conversion was complete and the website able to function (at least it seemed) until I removed the main project folder in order to rename it. Now I get the following error when I attempt to debug:

```
The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
Monet.Controllers.HomeController
SPAIN.Controllers.HomeController
```

I'm done a search of the entire solution for the old site name (SPAIN) and cannot find anything. Anyone have any ideas where I might want to looK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely still have the old compiled Assembly in the /bin dir; most likely named `Spain.dll` Since you changed the project name, the resulting assembly would have changed as well. If you didn't delete the old one, it's still there, and the app will still load it.